# Wrap each line with li

Tags: javascript

This is how I split the content of a textarea element into br-lines for displaying:

```
function linebreak(string) {
    return string.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
}
```

So this string...

```
Line 1\nLine 2
```

...gets...

```
Line 1<br>
Line 2<br>
```

But now I need each line wrapped as a `li`-element. The result should be:

```
<li>Line 1</li>
<li>Line 2</li>
```

This is how I would do that:

```
let result = '';
string.split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
    result += '<li>' + line + '</li>';
});
return result;
```

But is this the correct way to do that?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this approach. Also if your code is working fine and objective of this  question is to Improvements, [Code reviews](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the right place for it

Comment: `return string.split('\n').map(function(line) {
    return '<li>' + line + '</li>';
}).join('');`

Comment: @user3142695 Pranav C Balan method is quite good

Comment: `return '<li>' + string.split('\n').join('</li><li>') + '</li>';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace any sequence of non-linebreaks with `<li>...</li>`. Note that this also ignores empty lines:

```js
var text = 'first line\nsecond line\r\n\r\nthrid\n\n\n'
html = text.replace(/[^\r\n]+/g, '<li>$&</li>');
console.log(html)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** method to make it one linear

```
return string.split('\n').map(function(line) { return '<li>' + line + '</li>'; }).join('');
```

Or something tricky with **[`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** method

```
return '<li>' + string.split('\n').join('</li><li>') + '</li>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, you can use [**`split`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split your value into array then with **[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** wrap each one of them into a span/li whatever you want.

```js
function wrapValue() {
  var string = document.getElementById("textarea").value
    // append to ul 
  document.getElementById("myList").innerHTML = linebreak(string);
}
function linebreak(string){
  return string.split('\n')
  .reduce(function(c, n){
    return c + '<li>' + n + ' </li>'
  }, '')
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<button onclick="wrapValue()">Clic</button>
<ul id="myList">
</ul>
```

Or more shorter with fat arrow functions

```
wrapValue = () => {
  var string = document.getElementById("textarea").value
    // append to ul 
  document.getElementById("myList").innerHTML = linebreak(string);
}
linebreak = (string) => string.split('\n')
  .reduce((c, n) => c + '<li>' + n + ' </li>', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `string.replace` as well.

```js
function getLIs(str) {
  return "<li>" + str.replace(/\n/g, "</li><li>") + "</li>";
}

var str = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3";
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = getLIs(str);
```

```html
<ul id="content"></ul>
```